# rails 4 mongoid. mongoid_slug is not installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, slug, ruby-on-rails-4

I have started new project, installed mongoid, when i tried to install mongoid_slug it is giving me error.

I did not used --skip-active-record.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mongoid":
  In Gemfile:
    mongoid_slug (~> 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      mongoid (> 3.0) ruby

    mongoid (1.0.6)
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid_slug', '~> 3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the master branch of Mongoid as the Rails 4 compatibility was just [recently merged](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/2379) and no version has been released since.

```
gem 'mongoid', git: 'git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem 'mongoid_slug', '~> 3.0.0'
```